# Apply jQuery File Style plugin settings on newly created elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using [Mika Tuupola's File Style Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle)  and what I want to do is, apply this plugin to **newly created elements** with jQuery.

Here's my code :

```
<p><input type="file" name="" id="" /></p> 
  <p><button id="add">Add More...</button></p>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.filestyle.mini.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

     $("input[type=file]").filestyle({ 
         image: "choose-file.gif",
         imageheight : 22,
         imagewidth : 82,
         width : 250
     });


     $('#add').click(function() {

      $(this).parent().append('<p><input type="file" name="" id="" /></p>');

    });

  </script>
```

and when i click "add more" button, it displays like this:

[image]

so, what I'm doing wrong? can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the main problem is the plug-in. It wraps the provided element in a `div` that is set to `display: inline` that's why all of the new file elements are inline.

The only way to fix this is to modify the plugin to add an outer wrapper (like the `p` that you're trying to do). Download the [non minified plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.filestyle.js) and find the code that looks like this:

```
        $(self).before(filename);
        $(self).wrap(wrapper);
```

then make it look like this:

```
        $(self).wrap("<p/>");
        $(self).before(filename);
        $(self).wrap(wrapper);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xv2e/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().after('<p><input type="file" name="" id="" /></p>');

     $('input[type=file]').filestyle({ 
         image: "choose-file.gif",
         imageheight : 22,
         imagewidth : 82,
         width : 250
     });
```

Comment: Well, that both examples are working, but when I click add more button, this plugin add more nested elements inside of those created inputs.

here are the images http://imageshack.us/g/819/firebugv.png/

Comment: @Lado Lomidze: Switch `append` to `after`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried, even appendTo function, I even changed $(this) to some static ID, bot unfortunately I'm getting same result. 
It nests into nested elements on every single click.

Comment: @Lado Lomidze: Can you explain what's happening? It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LFBPt/

Comment: I've posted link above with images, what was happening when clicking on button http://imageshack.us/g/819/firebugv.png/ and in your example it works fine, but it won't apply style for created elements.

Comment: Also you will get same result, if you type  $('input[type=file]').filestyle( ... code several times ...

Answer (score 0):

Swap out the order...append first then bind the plugin.

```
 $('#add').live('click',function() {
       $(this).parent().append('<p><input type="file" name="" id="" /></p>');

      $("input[type=file]").filestyle({ 
           image: "choose-file.gif",
           imageheight : 22,
           imagewidth : 82,
           width : 250
       });



    });
```

Comment: in this situation first, by default created html element don't apply those rules, it applies only when i click on the button. 
is there any way, to "optimize" this code, that we won't need to dublicate filestyle settings twice, before 'live ' function and in that function?

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery Filestyle is more easy. http://markusslima.github.io/jquery-filestyle/

```
$(":file").jfilestyle({
   input: false,
   theme: "dark",
   iconName: "icon-plus",
   size: "250px"
});
```