# Any way to rerun a jQuery plugin after DOM modification?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got a form with file upload boxes and I'm using the jQuery Filestyle plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle) to style the inputs.  I've also got a simple JavaScript function to allow users to upload multiple files without having to submit the form.  My initial file upload input looks perfect but when the user clicks the Upload Additional File button and creates a new input, it's not styled at all.  I'm assuming this is because the plugin has already run at page load and modifying the DOM means that anything new won't have the styles applied.

So assuming that's the problem, my question is whether or not there's a way to recall the Filestyle jQuery on newly created file inputs?

Here's my Filestyle jQuery code:

```
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.filestyle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("input.file").filestyle({
            image: "/images/btn_select_file.gif",
            imageheight : 24,
            imagewidth : 115,
            width : 275,
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And my JavaScript DOM manipulation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fileCounter = 1;
function addFile() {
  fileCounter++;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id = 'file' + fileCounter;
  newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="form-item"><label for="file_' + inputCounter + '">Upload Additional File ' + (inputCounter) + '</label>\r<input type="file" name="file_' + inputCounter + '" id="file_' + inputCounter + '" class="file"><span class="space"><a href="javascript:removeFile(' + inputCounter + ');">Remove</a></span>';
  document.getElementById("files").appendChild(newdiv);
  document.getElementById("filecount").value = inputCounter;
}
</script>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195505/apply-jquery-file-style-plugin-settings-on-newly-created-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the plugin method at `function addFile()` function to let the plugin know to style that so your new `function addFile()` function can be something like

```
function addFile() {
  fileCounter++;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id = 'file' + fileCounter;
  newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="form-item"><label for="file_' + inputCounter + '">Upload Additional File ' + (inputCounter) + '</label>\r<input type="file" name="file_' + inputCounter + '" id="file_' + inputCounter + '" class="file"><span class="space"><a href="javascript:removeFile(' + inputCounter + ');">Remove</a></span>';
  document.getElementById("files").appendChild(newdiv);
  document.getElementById("filecount").value = inputCounter;
  $("input.file").last().filestyle({
            image: "/images/btn_select_file.gif",
            imageheight : 24,
            imagewidth : 115,
            width : 275,
        });
}
```

`$("input.file").last()` is selecting the newly added file input and adding styling to it through initializing the plugin for it.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this (though I haven't actually tested this)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputCounter = 1;
function addFile() {
  inputCounter++;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id = 'file' + inputCounter;
  newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="form-item"><label for="file_' + inputCounter + '">Upload Additional File ' + (inputCounter) + '</label>\r<input type="file" name="file_' + inputCounter + '" id="file_' + inputCounter + '" class="file"><span class="space"><a href="javascript:removeFile(' + inputCounter + ');">Remove</a></span>';
  document.getElementById("files").appendChild(newdiv);
  document.getElementById("filecount").value = inputCounter;
  $('#'+file_'+inputCounter).filestyle({
        image: "/images/btn_select_file.gif",
        imageheight : 24,
        imagewidth : 115,
        width : 275,
    });
}
</script>
```

Also, your variable "fileCounter" seems to be switched out for "inputCounter" which is probably causing you problems.

Comment: You're right about the fileCounter/inputCounter bit -- that's what I get for copy/pasting...thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add this after you create `newdiv`:

```
$(newdiv).filestyle({
    image: "/images/btn_select_file.gif",
    imageheight : 24,
    imagewidth : 115,
    width : 275,
});
```

Comment: He is passing `file input` element with class name `file` to the plugin. So passing the container might not work.