# Re-running a jQuery plugin against updated DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, plugins

I'm using a jQuery grid slider plugin that I'd like to run again after DOM manipulation.

I suspect my issue is similar to this - [Any way to rerun a jQuery plugin after DOM modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640981/any-way-to-rerun-a-jquery-plugin-after-dom-modification) - but my attempts aren't work.

Here's the setup:

When the page loads, the grid plugin js and the options js run against an unordered list, like such:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="g-container">
        <div class="g-slider">        
            <div class="tiles">
                <ul>                
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/image-01.jpg"></a><div><h1>automotive</h1></div></li>                                          
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/image-03.jpg"></a><div><h1>electronics</h1></div></li>                                             
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/image-02.jpg"></a><div><h1>medical</h1></div></li>                                             
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/image-11.jpg"></a><div><h1>automotive</h1></div></li>                                          
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/image-02.jpg"></a><div><h1>automotive</h1></div></li>                                          
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/image-09.jpg"></a><div><h1>medical</h1></div></li>                                             
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/image-11.jpg"></a><div><h1>electronics</h1></div></li>                                             
                </ul>             
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

...and create the grid slider. Here's an example of what it looks like: http://1.s3.envato.com/files/27300390/index.html

This all works fine.

(Long story short) I have a large list of categories that are all grouped together that I've placed in a div holder, like so:

```
<div id="listing-holder">
    <ul>                
        <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/car-01.jpg"></a><div><h1>automotive</h1></div></li>                                            
        <li><a href="#"><img src="Images/car-01.jpg"></a><div><h1>electronics</h1></div></li>                                           
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

These categories are dynamically created and in one large (hidden off the page) group. So there may be, say, 20 categories, and 100 items (in my example, the images). The items may appear in more than one category, though I only want to show one at a time.

Elsewhere on the page are some navigation links. When one of these links is clicked, the items in #listing-holder are copied into .tiles ul. Then it's name is checked against the header tags in .tiles ul, removing any items that do not match. Then, I want the plugin to run again so that the pagination and slider work as before the change, but with new paging (if it's more or less). Like so:

```
$("#left-menu").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    var itemClicked;
    itemClicked = $(this).text();
    $('.g-container .g-slider .tiles').html('');
    $('.g-container .g-slider .tiles').html($('#listing-holder').html());
    $(".g-container .g-slider .tiles h1:not(:contains(" + itemClicked + "))").closest('li').remove();
    init(); // this isn't working the way I expected it to
});
```

Here's the (pertinent information from the) options js:

```
$(document).ready(  
    function() {
        var $panel = $(".panel");       
        var $container = $panel.find(".g-container");
        ... // more variables

        $(".g-container").gridSlider({
            num_cols:5,
            num_rows:3,
            ... // more settings
        });

        $submitButton.click(function() {
            $container.undoChanges()
            .setGridSize($gridCol.val(),$gridRow.val())                   
            .setNoCategory($categories.filter(":checked").val() == "no")
            ... // more settings
            .updateChanges(); // this is in the grid.js         
            setPanelWidth();
        });

        $resetButton.click(function() {
            init();
            $submitButton.trigger("click");
        });

        var init = function() {
            $gridCol.val(5);
            $gridRow.val(3);
            ... // more settings
        }

        var setPanelWidth = function() {
            var width = $container.find(">div").outerWidth();
            if (width < panelWidth) {
                width = panelWidth; 
            }
            $panel.css({width:width, marginLeft:-width/2});
            ... // more settings
        }

        init();
    }
);
```

I've tried calling the init function, which does call it, but nothing seems to happen. I placed alerts at the beginning and end of the grid.js (which is minified), and they both fired, so it seems like it's going through.

I thought I'd have to use something like this:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = (function(){
        {
        // do something...
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

...but since I was able to call init from the options.js, I didn't go that route (but I'm willing to re-visit this, as I may have implented it incorrectly).

I've been at this for about a week, and I suspect I'm approaching this wrong, and could use some direction.

I think I could resolve the issue by creating all of the categories, then using something like getScript() to run afterwards. I think that would work. The issue is that there may potentially be several dozen categories, with items that may appear in several.

I figured (working with the hand dealt) that if I have just one list and pick from that list what I need depending on a click, that would be the route to go. I can do that successfully. It's just hooking it up to the slider that's not working.

Let me know if I need to provide further details.

Thanks.

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the grid-slider plugin. But have you tried completely destroying the container DOM and then re-creating and inserting it. Then call the .gridSlider function again on the newly created DOM?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this, but it didn't work. I was under pressure to get this resolved...so I went ahead and built the grid gallery slider myself (with the help of this - http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/). It didn't take long to build, and once built, I was able to successfully accomplish my objectives. Thanks.